# Im Trying To Run Python On Visual Studio Code But am Facing An File Not Found Error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, error-handling, pip

I installed python and was using it with PyCharm For A Couple of Weeks Today I wanted to Swap To Visual Studio Code Because of Some Features. I Created A File and Set It To Python From The Bottom Right Corner, When I Try Running and Debugging It Shows Me An Error Message That Says "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Untitled-1'PS C:> "

Comment: Save it before running it

Comment: I tried saving it but it didn't work. So I uninstalled Python, Visual Studio and installed them back, but now when I just write print("Hello World") it says "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: Maybe try switching default shell to `Command Prompt`?

Comment: It Worked Thank You So Much!

Comment: @JacobK Hey Can You Post This as An Answer, Not a Comment, I Need It in Answer Format To Approve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use cmd terminal and powershell terminal in VS Code.

When we run the code and the VSCode terminal is in the Python interactive window, the terminal displays: "`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`": (Because the Python interactive window recognizes Python code, the run button is to execute a command with a path.)

[image]

Solution:

1. Click the green run button in the upper right corner of VS Code:

   [image]
2. Or enter "Python" in the terminal to enter the Python interactive window, and then enter the code in the terminal:

   [image]

For using Python in VS Code you could refer to this document: [Python in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_run-hello-world).